# vba excel If condition error on final iteration

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm having the code takes the input from my checkboxes and grab data from the related worksheet. I ran it line by line and found out that it always gets a runtime error at the If statement on the final loop. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim chkBox  As MSForms.CheckBox

    ''''Add checkboxes based on total sheet count
    For counter = 1 To Sheets.count - 2
        Set chkBox = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & counter)
        chkBox.Caption = Sheets(counter + 2).Name
        chkBox.Left = 10
        chkBox.Top = 5 + ((counter - 1) * 20)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()

    Dim Series As Object
    Dim counter As Long

    '''Clear old series
    For Each Series In Sheets(2).SeriesCollection
        Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Next


    ''Cycle through checkboxes
    For counter = 1 To Sheets.count - 2
        ''If the box is checked then
        If Me.Frame1.Controls(counter).Value = True Then ''Error here on 4th iteration
            ''Add new series
            With Sheets(2).SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = Sheets(counter + 2).Range("$A$1")
                .XValues = Sheets(counter + 2).Range("$A$12:$A$25")
                .Values = Sheets(counter + 2).Range("$B$12:$B$25")
            End With

        End If

    Next counter

    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Also, a second problem is it always run on the wrong loop. If i check box 2 it'll run data for the box 1 sheet, 3 run for 2, 4 run for 3, and 1 run for 4. Can anyone explain the reason behind this?

EDIT: So as VincentG point out below, adding an explicit name "checkbox" in there did the trick (i didn't know you could do that). Index 1 was probably taken by one of the buttons or the frame in the user form, causing it to get off set.

Comment: You might have other controls than the checkboxes... for example the cmdContinue button. Try to use `Me.Frame1.Controls("CheckBox" & counter).Value = True`

Comment: *it always gets a runtime error*... Can you be more explicit? What error?

Comment: @VincentG your suggestion did the trick. It probably was one of the buttons or the frame was sitting in index 1 of the controls group.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main problem comes from the fact that the controls have to be accessed starting from index 0. So to loop over all controls, you would do something like

```
For counter = 0 To Me.Frame1.Controls.Count - 1
    Debug.Print counter; Me.Frame1.Controls(counter).Name
Next counter
```

So, when you stick to you code, I assume you have to change the if-statement to

```
If Me.Frame1.Controls(counter-1).Value = True Then
```

Comment: The zero index was me messing around to try and solve the second problem I mentioned up there.